# Can Django REST Swagger be used to generate static HTML documentation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, python-sphinx

I'm working on a new Django REST Framework project and I'm using Django REST Swagger to have provide beautiful documentation out of the box. However, I would like to share this documentation without having to spin up a staging machine or anything like that. I would just like to generate static sphinx-like documentation, without the fancy client features. I don't need to be able to actually hit the API endpoints. I just want a user friendly description of what endpoints exist, what they accept/return etc.

Is this possible using Django REST Swagger? If not, is there any tool that does this? Or do I just have to write sphinx documentation manually?

Comment: by any chance, did you find something ?

Comment: @LB40 unfortunately I didn't find anything. I had the feeling the the community somewhat wanted to push this more sophisticated type of documentation and there wasn't much will to implement what I described. But that is just my impression. I am not working on this project anymore so I don't know very well what the current situation is.

Answer (score -1):

Django REST Swagger allows you to generate documentation with swagger-ui. You can follow the [example](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/#example-app) as a starting point.

Here is an example of documentation using swagger-ui: http://petstore.swagger.io/